# Add a new column to big database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to add a new column to a table in my database. The table contains around 140 million rows and I'm not sure how to proceed without locking the database.

The database is in production and that's why this has to be as smooth as it can get.

I have read a lot but never really got the answer if this is a risky operation or not.
The new column is nullable and the default can be NULL. As i understood there is a bigger issue if the new column needs a default value.

I'd really appreciate some straight forward answers on this matter. Is this doable or not?

Comment: Do you have some low load windows?

Comment: want recreation of table with `create as select` be faster? we use this approach for oracle db. you then need to recreate all the constrains though.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If 2012 please supply the current table definition and details of the new column you are adding.

Comment: for the hackish solution you can add a new table with just the key to the other table and a value column which get populated as needed, and use a view with a `isnull` column for the default value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is eminently doable.

Adding a column where NULL is acceptable and has no default value does not require a long-running lock to add data to the table.

If you supply a default value, then SQL Server has to go and update each record in order to write that new column value into the row.

**How it works in general:**

```
+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Column is Nullable? | Default Value Supplied | Result                |
+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Yes                 | No                     | Quick Add (caveat)    |
| Yes                 | Yes                    | Long running lock     |
| No                  | No                     | Error                 |
| No                  | Yes                    | Long running lock     |
+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**The caveat bit:**

<strike>I can't remember off the top of my head what happens when you add a column that causes the size of the NULL bitmap to be expanded. I'd like to say that the NULL bitmap represents the nullability of all the the columns *currently in the row*, but I can't put my hand on my heart and say that's definitely true.</strike>

Edit -> @MartinSmith pointed out that the NULL bitmap will only expand when the row is changed, many thanks. However, as he also points out, if the size of the row expands past the 8060 byte limit in SQL Server 2012 then [a long running lock may still be required](http://rusanu.com/2012/02/16/adding-a-nullable-column-can-update-the-entire-table/). Many thanks * 2.

**Second caveat:**

Test it.

**Third and final caveat:**

No really, test it.

Comment: Yep metadata only change and the `NULL_BITMAP` won't expand until next time the row is updated.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I would like to work with you one day. :) Thanks and much respect.

Comment: Thanks! [Although I just remembered the situation does change a bit in 2012](http://rusanu.com/2012/02/16/adding-a-nullable-column-can-update-the-entire-table/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This pretty much sets it. I can add the column without risking a long lock on the table.

Comment: I might add that I'm running SQL Server 2008, does it make a difference?

Comment: @FREDRIK - It removes the risk of a long running lock if your change would push the row over 8060 byte limit, other than that no difference.

Comment: So in other words there is no risk in this operation? I'm going to do a full backup of the database tomorrow and add the new column on that one to see how it reacts and get an estimate on time. Better to be safe than sorry ;) Especially when the database is in production.

Comment: In other words there **should be** no risk. But there are two caveats saying 'test it' for a reason - and like you say, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 6):

My example is how do I add a new column to the table by tens of millions of rows and fill it by default value without long running lock

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD [CustomerTypeId] TINYINT NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_CustomerTypeId] DEFAULT 1 FOR [CustomerTypeId]
GO
DECLARE @batchSize bigint = 5000
    ,@rowcount int
    ,@MaxID int;

SET @rowcount = 1
SET @MaxID = 0

WHILE @rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    ;WITH upd as (
        SELECT TOP (@batchSize)
            [ID]
            ,[CustomerTypeId]
        FROM [dbo].[Customer] (NOLOCK)
        WHERE [CustomerTypeId] IS NULL
            AND [ID] > @MaxID
        ORDER BY [ID])

    UPDATE upd
          SET [CustomerTypeId] = 1
              ,@MaxID = CASE WHEN [ID] > @MaxID THEN [ID] ELSE @MaxID END

    SET @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
END;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  ALTER COLUMN [CustomerTypeId] TINYINT NOT NULL;
GO
```

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD [CustomerTypeId] TINYINT NULL` changes only the metadata (Sch-M locks) and lock time does not depend on the number of rows in a table

After that, I fill a new column by default value in small portions (5000 rows). I wait one second after each cycle so as not to block the table too aggressively. I have a int column "ID" as the primary clustered key

Finally, when all the new column is filled I change it to NOT NULL

Comment: You should describe what problem you are trying to solve. (I can deduce it from reading the code, but it isn't obvoius to the casual reader.)

Answer (score 5):

No one can tell how much time will the operation cost as this depend on many ither factors after all.

You should not be worried about the operations itself because the SQL Server is doing everything right:

> The Database Engine uses schema modification (Sch-M) locks during a
>   table data definition language (DDL) operation, such as adding a
>   column or dropping a table. During the time that it is held, the Sch-M
>   lock prevents concurrent access to the table. This means the Sch-M
>   lock blocks all outside operations until the lock is released.

I have never done `ALTER` operation on such amount of data and the only advice that I can give is to do it when there are not so many connections to the database (during the night).

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-adding-columns-to-a-table/) you can found more information about your question. Generally, `Matt Whitfield` is right and

> The only time that adding a column to a table results in a
>   size-of-data operation (i.e. an operation that modifies every row in a
>   table) is when the new column has a non-null default.

and when

> New column is nullable, with a NULL default. The table's metadata
>   records the fact that the new column exists but may not be in the
>   record. This is why the null bitmap also has a count of the number of
>   columns in that particular record. SQL Server can work out whether a
>   column is present in the record or not. So – this is NOT a
>   size-of-data operation – the existing table records are not updated
>   when the new column is added. The records will be updated only when
>   they are updated for some other operation.

Comment: That edit makes it all clear. SQL Server obviously don't care if the value is NULL (no need for recalculation), it only takes the new column in consideration if the column is changed after it's added?

Comment: Yes, it seems like this. But if you check the link provided by `Martin Smith` you will see that there is an exception. I am not familiar with the situation described there, but as I have read, I suppose the best thing to do is to: 1. Create the table on your local machine; 2. Add some records; 3. Alter the table adding the new column; 4. Check if the situation from the link will appears;

Comment: Yes, i will do some testing before executing on the production database of course. But as i understood that was only for SQL Server 2012 (by what he wrote, i can't access the link for some reason)? I'm currently running 2008.

Comment: @FREDRIK This is the link http://rusanu.com/2012/02/16/adding-a-nullable-column-can-update-the-entire-table/ and I believe the situation worth researching/testing before making the ALTER.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thanks for the help, the link is working now. I will read it and do some testing tomorrow. I'll come back with the testing results.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way that I usually do - Export that table and create new column at local and re-name the table name, then import table table, and just re-name the existing table and convert the first table name as it wa original.

Comment: with 140 million rows, that won't be smooth

Comment: @zencv: I have done this technique with 30-40 million, But you are right, need some special attension with 140 muillion